# DevExpress (C#) using Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, devexpress

I have been searching this all day , but i couldn't find a relevant answer , Is it possible to use `C#` + `DevExpress` on Firebase Database , or is there any way of accessing the Data from firebase while using `DevExpress` + `Firebase`.

If there's a solution or blog or an Example please share.

Comment: you really have searched for an answere?  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T392070

Comment: I have tried to read through the link , but theres no clear step by step example @MatthiasBurger, isn't there already made simple blog

Comment: because am still a beginner